# Microsoft Face API see database?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm using Microsoft Face API and I have many photos of persons there. I know that in azure database its saved only geometry of the face, not the whole photo. Now I want to see that data. I know that I can see part of this data, as I`m making requests, like to list all large person groups or to list all persons in the current large group. But I want to see all my data of persons, personId's, groups and photos geometry which is saved in azure's database from azure portal or somewhere else. 
And my question is:

**Can I see all my data which is saved in azure's database?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Microsoft Face API` is a SaaS service: you are not hosting any of the resources used by the API in your own subscription. So the main point is: **there is no data saved in your Azure database.**

You will not have direct access to the resources hosting the metadata used for your saved faces, all you can access is the data accessible through the API: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

So if you want to get the Face Landmarks, you can only get them during your call to `Detect` method, which have the following properties:

> An array of 27-point face landmarks pointing to the important
>   positions of face components. To return this, it requires
>   "returnFaceLandmarks" parameter to be true.

As a result, you will get the following items:

```
"faceLandmarks": {
    "pupilLeft": {
        "x": 412.7,
        "y": 78.4
    },
    "pupilRight": {
        "x": 446.8,
        "y": 74.2
    },
    "noseTip": {
        "x": 437.7,
        "y": 92.4
    },
    "mouthLeft": {
        "x": 417.8,
        "y": 114.4
    },
    "mouthRight": {
        "x": 451.3,
        "y": 109.3
    },
    "eyebrowLeftOuter": {
        "x": 397.9,
        "y": 78.5
    },
    "eyebrowLeftInner": {
        "x": 425.4,
        "y": 70.5
    },
    "eyeLeftOuter": {
        "x": 406.7,
        "y": 80.6
    },
    "eyeLeftTop": {
        "x": 412.2,
        "y": 76.2
    },
    "eyeLeftBottom": {
        "x": 413.0,
        "y": 80.1
    },
    "eyeLeftInner": {
        "x": 418.9,
        "y": 78.0
    },
    "eyebrowRightInner": {
        "x": 4.8,
        "y": 69.7
    },
    "eyebrowRightOuter": {
        "x": 5.5,
        "y": 68.5
    },
    "eyeRightInner": {
        "x": 441.5,
        "y": 75.0
    },
    "eyeRightTop": {
        "x": 446.4,
        "y": 71.7
    },
    "eyeRightBottom": {
        "x": 447.0,
        "y": 75.3
    },
    "eyeRightOuter": {
        "x": 451.7,
        "y": 73.4
    },
    "noseRootLeft": {
        "x": 428.0,
        "y": 77.1
    },
    "noseRootRight": {
        "x": 435.8,
        "y": 75.6
    },
    "noseLeftAlarTop": {
        "x": 428.3,
        "y": 89.7
    },
    "noseRightAlarTop": {
        "x": 442.2,
        "y": 87.0
    },
    "noseLeftAlarOutTip": {
        "x": 424.3,
        "y": 96.4
    },
    "noseRightAlarOutTip": {
        "x": 446.6,
        "y": 92.5
    },
    "upperLipTop": {
        "x": 437.6,
        "y": 105.9
    },
    "upperLipBottom": {
        "x": 437.6,
        "y": 108.2
    },
    "underLipTop": {
        "x": 436.8,
        "y": 111.4
    },
    "underLipBottom": {
        "x": 437.3,
        "y": 114.5
    }
},
```

If you need to use these details later if you persist the face, I can suggest 2 options:

- host on your subscription a database where you will store these settings and the persistedFaceId
- or pass those values in the [`userData`](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395250) field when you are persisting the values. This field is: `User-specified data about the face list for any purpose. The maximum length is 1KB`. Then you can get those fields later using Get method